# How to create firestore transaction where target document needs to be found

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way to create a firestore transaction where i find a document from a query and then modify this document in a transaction.

Something along those lines (kotlin):

```java
firestore.runTransaction { transaction ->

  val snapshot = transaction.get(db.collection("document")
      .whereEqualTo("someField", null)
      .orderBy("creationDate", ASCENDING)
      .limit(1L))

  val myObject = snapshot.toObject(MyObject::class.java)
  myObject.someFiled = "123"
  transaction.set(snapshot.reference, myObject)
}
```

The problem here is that the query returned by the `.limit(1)` method is not a DocumentReference, which is the only type the transaction accepts. Therefore my question is, how can such a transaction be achieved in java/kotlin?

I have seen something similar in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@feloy/building-a-multi-player-board-game-with-firebase-firestore-functions-part-1-17527c5716c5) using the admin sdk:

```
  return trs.get(db.collection('rooms')
    .where('full', '==', false)
    .where('size', '==', size)
    .limit(1));
```

Comment: Hi @Moritz  did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

After investigation looks like you can't do that in Kotlin/Java it is not supported. You will have to create cloud function and do something similar to:

```
exports.executeTransaction = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const db = admin.firestore();

    const query = db
        .collection('collection')
        .where('name', '==', 'name')
        .limit(1);

    db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return transaction
            .get(query)
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                const gameDocSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
                const gameData = gameDocSnapshot.data();
                transaction.update(gameDocSnapshot.ref, { name: 'change' });
                return gameData;
            })
    })
        .then((gameData) => {
            res.send(gameData);
            console.log('Transaction successfully committed!', gameData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.send('Transaction failed:' + error);
            console.log('Transaction failed:', error);
        });
});
```

Comment: What will happen if for example the scope of the query changes while the transaction is still running and not reached to completion. Will the subsequent write operations that could possibly change the query's scope will get rejected or does the transaction retries itself if the query's scope changes in between?
I didn't find any thing in official firebase documentation regarding this edge case.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about java/kotlin but here is how I did it in TypeScript/JavaScript in a Cloud Function.

```
const beerTapIndex: number = parseInt(req.params.beerTapIndex);
const firestore: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore = admin.firestore();

firestore
    .runTransaction((transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
        const query: FirebaseFirestore.Query = firestore
            .collection('beerOnTap')
            .where('tapIndexOrder', '==', beerTapIndex)
            .limit(1);

        return transaction
            .get(query)
            .then((snapshot: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot) => {
                const beerTapDoc: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot = snapshot.docs[0];
                const beerTapData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData = beerTapDoc.data();
                const beerTapRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference = firestore
                    .collection('beerOnTap')
                    .doc(beerTapDoc.id);

                transaction.update(beerTapRef, {enabled: !beerTapData.enabled});

                return beerTapData;
            })
    })
    .then((beerTapData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData) =>  {
        console.log('Transaction successfully committed!', beerTapData);
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.log('Transaction failed:', error);
    });
```

Plan JavaScript Version

```
const beerTapIndex = parseInt(req.params.beerTapIndex);
const firestore = admin.firestore();

firestore
    .runTransaction((transaction) => {
        const query = firestore
            .collection('beerOnTap')
            .where('tapIndexOrder', '==', beerTapIndex)
            .limit(1);

        return transaction
            .get(query)
            .then((snapshot) => {
                const beerTapDoc = snapshot.docs[0];
                const beerTapData = beerTapDoc.data();
                const beerTapRef = firestore
                    .collection('beerOnTap')
                    .doc(beerTapDoc.id);

                transaction.update(beerTapRef, {enabled: !beerTapData.enabled});

                return beerTapData;
            })
    })
    .then((beerTapData) =>  {
        console.log('Transaction successfully committed!', beerTapData);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Transaction failed:', error);
    });
```

Found my answer here: https://medium.com/@feloy/building-a-multi-player-board-game-with-firebase-firestore-functions-part-1-17527c5716c5

Async/Await Version

```
private async _tapPouringStart(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): Promise<void> {
    const beerTapIndex: number = parseInt(req.params.beerTapIndex);
    const firestore: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore = admin.firestore();

    try {
        await firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction: FirebaseFirestore.Transaction) => {
            const query: FirebaseFirestore.Query = firestore
                .collection('beerOnTap')
                .where('tapIndexOrder', '==', beerTapIndex)
                .limit(1);

            const snapshot: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot = await transaction.get(query);

            const beerTapDoc: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot = snapshot.docs[0];
            const beerTapData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData = beerTapDoc.data();
            const beerTapRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference = firestore
                .collection('beerOnTap')
                .doc(beerTapDoc.id);

            transaction.update(beerTapRef, {enabled: !beerTapData.enabled});

            const beerTapModel = new BeerTapModel({
                ...beerTapData,
                tapId: beerTapDoc.id,
            });

            res.send(beerTapModel);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do it but until Google supports it, you could do the following way.

You can first get the document ID the normal way and then use that document ID to get a `DocumentReference` object.

Taking context from your code, it would look something like this,

```
// Get the document Id
db.collection("document")
        .whereEqualTo("someField", null)
        .orderBy("creationDate", ASCENDING)
        .limit(1L)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { querySnapshot ->
            if (querySnapshot.isSuccessful) {
                val docId = querySnapshot.result.documents.first().id
                val docRef = db.document(docId)

                // Now do transaction related work
                val snapshot = tx.get(docRef)
                val myObject = snapshot.toObject(MyObject::class.java)
                myObject.someFiled = "123"
                transaction.set(snapshot.reference, myObject)
            }
        }
```

It worked for me this way, but I haven't checked it thoroughly for you code. Let me know if you find a problem. Will try to correct it. Hope it helps!