# Editing a Document based on query result in Firestore Transaction

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently doing a project on Firestore database with Android SDK. I need to write a Transaction, in which I want to edit a "destination" document in "destinations" collection, only when another collection named "batches" does not have any document with its field name "destionId" set to the editing destination document ID. I am checking that with a query with .limit(1) set

Now, I want to do this in a Transaction since this app is real time and will be used by so many people at the same time. If I did not use transaction, then the possibility is that another person may add a "batch" document with this destinationId right between my query for checking and actual editing of the destination document. So, I want to run the query and check batches collection every time the transaction retries.

But I'm not sure how to run the Firestore query inside the transaction as its asynchronous. I believe that there is no way to make a blocking query request in Android SDK. please correct me if wrong.

Can someone help me with an idea of how to resolve this conflict? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Doug answered: you can't do a query inside a transaction. That means you must do the query outside of the transaction, and load the relevant documents inside the transaction. I'm not sure if that will work here though, as I find it quite hard to parse the text into (pseudo) code. You might want to update the question with some (pseudo) code to make it easier for us to reason about the use-case/problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't perform a query inside a transaction, or make a transaction contingent on an unchanging set of query results.  You can only fetch individual documents by their ID, with the intent to change them later in that transaction.

Answer (score 3):

In case it's helpful to others, running a transaction that operates on a query result *is* possible via the admin SDK (in contrast to the Java client-side SDK).  Check out the doc on this [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get).

> Retrieve a document or a query result from the database. Holds a pessimistic lock on all returned documents.

This capability is also mentioned in the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50035765/3423866).  Notice that on the corresponding client-side JS SDK [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction.html#get), the argument to the `get` function only accepts a `documentRef`.